# How to get a unique set of parent models after querying on child

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-activerecord

`Order` `has_many` `Items` is the relationship.

So let's say I have something like the following 2 orders with items in the database:

```
Order1 {email: alpha@example.com, items_attributes:
    [{name: "apple"},
     {name: "peach"}]
}
Order2 {email: beta@example.com, items_attributes:
    [{name: "apple"},
     {name: "apple"}]
}
```

I'm running queries for Order based on child attributes. So let's say I want the emails of all the orders where they have an Item that's an apple. If I set up the query as so:

```
orders = Order.joins(:items).where(items: {name:"apple"})
```

Then the result, because it's pulling at the `Item` level, will be such that:

```
orders.count = 3
orders.pluck(:email) = ["alpha@exmaple.com", "beta@example.com", "beta@example.com"]
```

But my desired outcome is actually to know what unique orders there are (I don't care that `beta@example.com` has 2 apples, only that they have at least 1), so something like:

```
orders.count = 2
orders.pluck(:email) = ["alpha@exmaple.com", "beta@example.com"]
```

How do I do this?

If I do `orders.select(:id).distinct`, this will fix the problem such that `orders.count == 2`, BUT this distorts the result (no longer creates AR objects), so that I can't iterate over it. So the below is fine

```
deduped_orders = orders.select(:id).distinct
deduped_orders.count = 2
deduped_orders.pluck(:email) = ["alpha@exmaple.com", "beta@example.com"]
```

But then the below does NOT work:

```
deduped_orders.each do |o|
  puts o.email # ActiveModel::MissingAttributeError: missing attribute: email
end
```

Like I basically want the output of `orders`, but in a unique way.

Answer (score 1):

I find using subqueries instead of joins a bit cleaner for this sort of thing:

```
Order.where(id: Item.select(:order_id).where(name: 'apple'))
```

that ends up with this (more or less) SQL:

```
select *
from orders
where id in (
  select order_id
  from items
  where name = 'apple'
)
```

and the `in (...)` will clear up duplicates for you. Using a subquery also clearly expresses what you want to do–you want the orders that have an item named `'apple'`–and the query says exactly that.

Answer (score 0):

use `.uniq` instead of `.distinct`

```
deduped_orders = orders.select(:id).uniq
deduped_orders.count = 2
deduped_orders.pluck(:email) = ["alpha@exmaple.com", "beta@example.com"]
```

Comment: this didn' work `deduped_orders.first.email` generated the same `ActiveModel::MissingAttributeError: missing attribute: email` error

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep all the attributes of orders use `group`

```
deduped_orders = orders.group(:id).distinct

deduped_orders.each do |o|
  puts o.email
end
#=> output: "alpha@exmaple.com", "beta@example.com"
```

Comment: if I just do `orders.group(:id)` I get an anomalous attribute error because `id` is an attribute for both orders and items. So i tried `orders.group("orders.id")` and this still failed

Comment: GROUP BY (i.e. `#group`) is meant for grouping rows for aggregate functions, using it to collapse duplicates is database-specific.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to remove `select(:id)`

```
orders = Order.joins(:items).where(items: {name:"apple"}).distinct

orders.pluck(:email)
# => ["alpha@exmaple.com", "beta@example.com"]

orders = deduped_orders
deduped_orders.each do |o| 
  puts o.email # loop twice
end
```